# Probability when throwing two dice, given a condition

Tags: probability

I have this problem about probability:

> By throwing two dice into the air, one observes that the sum of the
>   numbers that appear is at least seven. The probability of that on the
>   second dice, the number $4$ appears is:

And the only way I found to solve this was by writing all possible combinations that are greater than or equal to 7.

```
1+6
2+5
2+6
3+4
3+5
3+6
4+3
4+4
4+5
4+6
5+2
5+3
5+4
5+5
5+6
6+1
6+2
6+3
6+4
6+5
6+6
```

And in 4 cases the number of the second dice is 4:

```
3 + 4
4 + 4
5 + 4
6 + 4
```

So, the probability is $\frac{4}{21}$. But I think that this solution is too slow, could you help me with a faster thought to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you happened to notice a pattern in the number of ways to roll a sum of exactly $k$ on two dice (hint: arrange the results in a two-dimensional array), then you might be able to find the size of the sample space with a fairly well-known formula, but otherwise none of the methods that come to mind are really going to be any faster than exhaustive enumeration.

Comment: You should never write out every possibility if you can help it if you can't count it on one hand.  You could speed this up by knowing that there are $6$ ways to get a sum of seven, $5$ ways to get a sum of eight, ... $2$ ways to get a sum of eleven and $1$ way to get a sum of twelve for a total of $1+2+3+4+5+6 = \frac{6\cdot 7}{2} = 21$ different situations we are interested in, and the specific cases we are interested in are $3+4,4+4,...6+4$ for a total of four, giving $\frac{4}{21}$.

Comment: If it were a more massive problem, then perhaps you could save some additional time by applying Bayes' theorem, but that seems overkill for this.

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of ways you can throw a total of $7$ or more when the second die shows a $4$, you cannot count the ways much quicker than writing the list of four possible throws.

(You may be able to do it a *little* quicker, but not *much* quicker, because that way is already quick.)

What you do *not* have to do is to write out all $21$ throws with sums of $7$ or more in order to pick out that list of four throws. Just write $4$ for the second die and see what possibilities work for the first die.

Then figure out a faster way to count the $21$ throws. Here’s one way: there are $6$ ways to throw $7$ and the rest of the distribution is symmetric around $7,$ so half the other $30$ throws are greater than $7$ and the other half are less. And $6+30/2=21.$

Answer (score 0):

You can define event A as the sum of numbers is at least 7 and event B as the number 4 appears on the second dice. Then you can calculate the conditional probability  $$P(B|A)= \frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$